# Get size of files with Google Drive API v3

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm extracting some data from the drive API:

```
response = service.files().list(q=q_parameter, spaces='drive', fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name,mimeType, webViewLink, owners, capabilities, createdTime, modifiedTime, size)', pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

I'm saving the response in a JSON file, but the size is not being saved...

[image: JSON response]

Drive API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you wanna to get size of files using Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem! Everything works fine. The native drive files don't take up space.

Answer (score 2):

Use fields * and it will download all of the metadata.   If you hadent set up the limitation fields correctly the data would have returned null

```
response = service.files().list(q=q_parameter, spaces='drive', fields='*', pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

Comment: That's was not the problem! I have found the solution. The native drive files don't take up space :)